# How can I associate Class A with Class B, and the return a reference to class B from a method located in class A?

Tags: java, class, associations

Class A

```
    public class Customer {

// Add instance varables
private String lName;
private String fName;
private String address;
private String zip;

//    A constructor that initializes the last name, first name, address, and zip code.
public Customer(String lN, String fN, String addr, String zi) {
    lName = lN;
    fName = fN;
    address = addr;
    zip = zi;
}


//    setAccount(Account a) - Sets the Account for this customer


}

//    getAccount() - Returns a reference to the Account object associated with this customer
public Account getAccount(){
    return();
}
```

}

I don't know how to "reference" an object from within another class. I can't create the object because I want everything to be universal, and able to be created later and have the two classes properly associated with one another.

Class B

```
    public class Account {

// Add instance variables
private String accountNumber;
private double balance;
private Customer customer;


// A constructor that initializes the account number and Customer, and sets the blance to zero.
public Account(String aN, Customer c) {
    accountNumber = aN;
    balance = 0.00;
    customer = c;
}
```

So I can't understand how to create the set account and get account methods in class A

Comment: You are attempting to create circular references here; remember a `Customer` might have more than one `Account`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Customer has a single Account, add from Customer:

```
private Account account;

public void setAccount( Account account ){ this.account = account; }

public Account getAccount(  ){ return account; }
```

and remove everything related with Customer from Account. Then you can use getAccount() from A (Customer) to return a reference to B (Account)

If you want the other way (Accounts have Customers):

```
public class Account {

// Add instance variables
private String accountNumber;
private double balance;
private Customer customer;


public Account(String aN) {
    accountNumber = aN;
    balance = 0.00;
}

public Customer getCustomer(){ return customer;}
public void setCustomer(Customer customer){ this.customer = customer;}

}
```

...then you can use getCustomer() from A (Account) to get a reference to B (Customer)

Which class has the reference to the other depends completely on the design of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a chicken-and-hen problem. One object has to be instantiated first. It does not matter which one it is, but one has to be it. In case the customer and account are bound to each other permanently I would highly recommend making the fields 'final'.

```
class Customer {

    private final Account account;

    public Customer() {
        account = new Account(this);
    }

    public Account getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

}

class Account {

    private final Customer customer;

    public Account(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

}
```